# Remove indentation and hang in itemize environment in beamer

Tags: beamer, indentation, itemize, hang

I am using `\setlength{\itemindent}{-1em}` or `\itemindent=-13pt` to reduce horizontal space before items in beamer, but the problem is the hang for the second line.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{test}
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
    \begin{enumerate} \setlength{\itemindent}{-1em}
        %\itemindent=-13pt
        \item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 
        \item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 
        \begin{enumerate}\setlength{\itemindent}{-2em}
            \item  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum            
            \item  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum           
            \item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adjust `\leftmargini`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{test}
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}
    \setlength{\leftmarginii}{0em}
    \setlength{\leftmarginiii}{0em}    
    \begin{enumerate} 
        \item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 
        \item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum            
            \item  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum           
            \item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]